# Numerical division format output question

Tags: mysql, sql

I have my results as:

```
| ad_id | ctr   |
+-------+-------+
| 1     | 66.67 |
| 3     | 50.00 |
| 2     | 33.33 |
| 5     | 0.00  |
+-------+-------+
```

My query is below as

```
select ad_id, coalesce(Round(total_clicks / (total_clicks + total_views) * 100,2),0) as ctr
from (
    
    select ad_id, 
           sum(case when action = 'Clicked' then 1 else 0 end) as total_clicks,
           sum(case when action = 'Viewed' then 1 else 0 end) as total_views
    from ads
    group by 1) a
    group by 1
    order by 2 desc, 1 asc
```

I know sometimes cast as decimal or float is needed when calculating like this, as if my first row in result output is 66.67, in the calculation in my query it is actually .06666667 but shouldn't this calculate as 0 since I haven't casted as a numeric or decimal? I only * 100 but even then should that have not only given me 66? or does the round kind of convert to decimal anyway? Just confused as I know typically in sql when you divide you need to cast to decimal to make sure output has decimals? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MySQL, the `/` operator always performs double or decimal arithmetic. If you want integer division use `DIV`

```
SELECT 1 / 2 => 0.5
SELECT 1 DIV 2 => 0
```

Comment: thanks, so in mysql I dont need to worry about casting to numeric or decimal when running a division?

Comment: @Chris90 no, but you still need to worry about dividing by 0.  That results in NULL

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you write the query as:

```
select ad_id, avg( action = 'Clicked' ) as ctr
from ads
where action in ('Clicked', 'Viewed')
group by 1;
```

MySQL treats booleans as numbers in a number context -- with `1` for true and `0` for false.  Average works on decimal numbers, so no need to worry about integer averages in this case.

Comment: Thanks, but my method was still correct output right?

Comment: @Chris90 . . . Your method is not wrong.  It is more verbose and less performant.